# Wavefront obj formatted string as a source for a Viro3DObject instead of using require('/src/theobj.obj') (in react native)

Tags: react-native, 3d, android-augmented-reality

is it possible to use an .obj notation formatted string as a Viro3DObject* source? So instead of pointing to my /src/models i use a gigantic string which is exactly the same as what an obj file would contain in my local assets?

like so:

```
objStr = "mtllib objmtl.mtl v  -0.7752 0.1285 0.3030 v  -0.8354 0.1285 0.3641 v  -0.8354 0.1311 0.3641 v  -0.7752 0.1311 0.3030 etc..."


let the3DObject = <Viro3DObject>         
                       source={objStr}
                  </Viro3DObject>
```

(same goes for the other resources like mtl and images)

And then add the3DObject to the AR or VR scene.

'*'  *(from the Viro React framework from Viro Media)*

Comment: I'd try opening up a github issue to ask this question. Unfortunately there's not much on stack overflow relating to Viro (which I myself am starting to use).